# Convergence of parts of a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be a convergent series, can we have  $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n=0$? What about the case that $a_n$ is non-negative?

I know that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if $a_n$ is non-negative, but how can we prove that it converges to $0$?

I encountered this in the first proof of [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)
.

Comment: Suppose the series of non-negative terms $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges. Let $s=\sum_1^\infty a_n$, and let $s_m:=a_1+\cdots+a_m$ $(m=1,2,\ldots)$.  For $m=1,2,\ldots$, let $c_m:=|s_m-s|$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then there is a positive integer $M$ so that $|s_m-s|<\varepsilon$ whenever $m>M$. In other words, $\lim_{m \to \infty} c_m=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the series converges, suppose it converges to some finite value, $A$. We get,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = A$$

Then we know,

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n - \sum_{n = 1}^{m} a_n\\
&= A - \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n
\end{align*}$$

Thus, taking limits we have,

$$ \begin{align*}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n &=  \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \left(A - \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n\right)\\
&= A -\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n\\
&= A - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\\
&= A - A \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

Notice that this works regardless of whether $a_n$ is nonnegative or not.